# How to block alert message in pop-up page?

Tags: javascript

```
var win = window.open('url')
```

I want to block alert message in popup window, win.

I know that block alert message in current window.

```
window.alert = function() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

This code replace origin alert message.

But, How to does pop-up pages similarly?

```
win.window.alert = function() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

This is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL is on the same domain, this should work (the returned `win` is already a `Window` object):

```
win.alert = function() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

If it's not from the same domain, there's nothing you can do; the same-origin policy forbids messing with the scope of pages loaded from other origins, for security reasons.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> The returned `Window` reference can be used to access properties and methods of the new window as long as it complies with [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) security requirements.